# Javascript - onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I'm not sure why, but my onclick event for one of my buttons is not working. It's the one I'm using to do the calculations on my form. I have two others, that are functioning correctly, one triggers a print function, and the other redirects to another page.

Here's the Javascript for the 3 buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function previewFunction() {
    window.location.href = "preview.php";
}

function printFunction() {
    window.print();
}

function calculateFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById("limit");
    var limit = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var rate = .0075;
    var fee = .0025;

    var cost = (rate + fee) * limit;
    document.getElementById("cost").innerHtml = cost;
}

</script>
```

The calculateFunction() is the one that's not working.

Here's the HTML for the calculate button / cost span:

```
<tr>
    <th align="center"><input class="buttonStuff" type="button" onclick="calculateFunction()" value="Calculate" /></th>
    <th valign="bottom" align="center"><span style="font-size: 20pt;">Cost: </h3><span id="cost" style="text-decoration:underline;">$0.00</span></th>
</tr>
```

Here's the HTML for the two that do work:

```
<tr class="container">
    <td width="25%" align="center"><input class="buttonStuff" type="button" onclick="previewFunction()" value="Preview" /></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><input type="button" class="buttonStuff" onclick="printFunction()" value="Print" /></td>
</tr>
```

Nothing happens when I click Calculate. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, maybe not.

Thanks for any help you can provide. Let me know if I need to post more code.

Comment: Do you have an element with id of `limit`?

Comment: Does your console give you any error?

Comment: You misspelled `innerHTML`. Note that 'HTML' is all caps.

Comment: **Always** have your browser developer console open when investigating issues with page styles or code issues.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, best advice for my problem. There was more wrong than the uppercase HTML. Got it working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, it's `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`

```
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = cost;
```

Comment: There was more wrong than this, but this was also a problem, so I'll give you the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had `child.js` and a `common.js` files. In my case, My HTML file was using both the JS files and both of them had a function with the same name,

> child.js

```
function calculateFunction(){...}
```

and also

> common.js

```
function calculateFunction(){...}
```

After I remove one of these my code works fine and onclick started working. hope this helps!